# Install old php, MYSQL on Linux

Tags: php, mysql, linux, server, lampp

I need to install on Linux server Apache, MYSQL (5.0 - 5.1) and PHP (5.1 - 5.3).

Maybe someone can give a guide how to do it step by step? I want to learn it.
Thanks!

Comment: On which OS will you install?

Comment: On CentOS, or UBUNTU_server

Comment: Start here http://www.server-world.info/en/

Comment: You should not use such old versions for any learning.

Comment: I need old versions for my work, for clients :)

Comment: Bad and unfortunate thing.. Those are mostly unsupported and probably not secure anymore.

Comment: I know, but this is the company's policy that is too expensive Change the system

Comment: I'm beginner with Linux, but not with windows :)

Comment: I have mysql, apache, php, but from php i  get error "mysql_query()" Does not Exist. How to connect now MYSQL to PHP?

Comment: you need probably some package like php-mysql to install proper client library to php